# Are case conversions locale-independent on the ASCII character set?

Tags: localization, ascii

If I have a string containing only characters from the ASCII set (0 to 127), can I guarantee that converting to upper case or lower case will result in a consistent value regardless of any localisation settings?

For example, can I know that "Hello World" will become "hello world" and "HELLO WORLD" under conversions to upper and lower case without knowing anything about localisation?

Comment: I believe not, due to Turkish I.

Comment: @SLaks Is that character in ASCII?

Comment: @delnan: `i` is, and case conversions are not guaranteed to stay within the lower ASCII range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as @SLaks writes in a comment, Turkish has special rules for “i”: the uppercase equivalent of “i” is I with dot above, “İ”, and the lowercase equivalent of “I” is dotless i, “ı”. The same applies to Azeri, a close relative of Turkish.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the function doing the conversion. You'd be fine with all the C library functions for example.